# Is there a way to see loot on the ground?

Tags: diablo-ii

I could swear there is a way to see loot on the ground with a "name bubble".  Often times it drops behind something on screen and in big fights I just forget where it dropped.  Many items blend in the with the background and while I can hunt with the mouse, I'm sure I'm missing stuff.  Is there a way to see all the loot that is on the ground at any given time?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Hold <kbd>Alt</kbd> to show the names of all the loot on the screen.

From here, you can even click on the names that appear to pick the items up, so you don't have to hunt with your mouse in the general area on the ground to find the loot.

Comment: That's it.  I recall now, running everywhere with ALT held down, so that when I toggled mini map with Tab I'd end up leaving the window and cussing.  Ahh... memories...

Comment: Who played Diablo2 and didn't alt-tab never really played diablo2, if you know what I means xD

Comment: @MichelAyres That's why I always changed the hotkey to something else :)

Comment: @MichaelAyres I don't remember accidentally alt-tabbing. However, there were memorable times when I was holding down alt to look at items, and decided to raise more skeletons at the same time. With raise skeleton bound to F4.

Comment: One of the reasons why I changed the "show item names" key to Shift and used Alt for the minimap toggle. I always ran around with the map on, so I hit it once per game and didn't touch it again.

Answer (score -3):

Try pressing/holding <kbd>Alt</kbd> or <kbd>Tab</kbd>

:)

Comment: Just not both at the same time

Comment: This is wrong. Tab has nothing to do with items.

Comment: Tab defaults to the overlay mini-map